QField crashes when trying to delete objects
A project that is to be used by several mappers contains three geopackage layers that are to be processed. There are also several shapefiles and geopackages for orientation. Several WMS services as background maps.
During testing, I noticed that the project is loaded on various Android devices (tablets, smartphones from different manufacturers) and that you can also make entries. But as soon as you try to delete an object, QField crashes without an error message. After that, the app can no longer be opened properly. QField only works again without crashing once the project has been deleted. After reloading the project, QField crashes again and again when trying to delete a previously created object.
What is noticeable is that QField zooms in very far when a point object is selected, so that the aerial image from the WMS layer can only be recognised as pixels. Could this be the problem? If so, how can this be prevented?
I have already tried various things in the settings in QField. For example, map canvas rendering quality set to lowest quality, attribute table activated in full screen and navigation with fixed scale activated.
We work with cable export.

Sounds like a corruption of the project, or an invalid geometry somewhere. Check all geometries. If no invalid geometries, rebuild the project from scratch - you can save all styles for each layer to ease this task.
